# Android App Force Closes on Error Layout

Tags: java, android, layout, android-asynctask, forceclose

I have a bit of code which connects to the internet and pulls data - if it is unable to connect to the URL - it displays an error screen however when it reaches that error screen/layout the user recieves a force close error and I need to figure out how to prevent that from happening.

SOURCE:

```
if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

        try {
            // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the
            // xml
            setContentView(R.layout.updating);
            // This image view has the updating text to be progressively
            // updated
            // with dots addition
            ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);
            // Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
            // Set updating button to drawable animation
            loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
            loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

            ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);
            // Button goButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty);
            // Set updating button to drawable animation
            loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
            loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();

            // mProgressImageview = (ImageView)
            // findViewById(R.id.updating_text);
            // mLoadingCircle = (ImageView)
            // findViewById(R.id.updating_hand);

            tasks.execute("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3177165644456456/GetPhoneSettings-rsp-eng.xml");
            if (tasks.get() != null) {
                stream = tasks.getInputStream();
                Log.v("CfA", "here");

            }else {
                setContentView(R.layout.error);
                //finish();
            }
```

LOGCAT:

```
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253): Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:257)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:311)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.getValues(ConfigFinalActivity.java:355)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.InsertAPN(ConfigFinalActivity.java:324)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.updateTable(ConfigFinalActivity.java:676)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity.access$0(ConfigFinalActivity.java:643)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.doInBackground(ConfigFinalActivity.java:548)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at com.project.example.datasettings.ConfigFinalActivity$TableUpdateRequestTask.doInBackground(ConfigFinalActivity.java:1)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-01 00:14:28.175: E/AndroidRuntime(5253):     ... 4 more
01-01 00:14:28.400: D/CLIPBOARD(5253): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
```

Comment: You might want to edit out that Dropbox link...

Answer (score 1):

`Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0`

Wherever you are using an array/arraylist, check if it is empty before:

```
MyObject obj = myArray[0];            // For an array

MyObject obj = myArrayList.get(0);    // For an arraylist
```

From the `logcat` output you have posted, it looks like `myArray[0]` is in your `AsyncTask`. Edit the question with your AsyncTask's code.

For an array, perform the following check:

```
if (myArray.length > 0) {

    // go crazy within bounds

}
```

For an arraylist:

```
if (myArrayList.size() > 0) {

    // go crazy within bounds

}
```

Comment: Seems to be an ArrayList which is causing the error. Initialized but empty. ConfigFinalActivity.java:355

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @vikram, before you play with Arrays check

```
if(yourArray.size() > 0){
  //
}
```

If you change your Array "on the fly", use `Vector` instead (Vector is synchronized.), to prevent  this issue.

Or use:

```
List yourArray= Collections.synchronizedList (yourArray);
```